# How to add a video from gallery and play it on a videoview in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been making an app where you can attach images and videos. I am able to attach images and show it to the user, but I am unable to show the user the video they chose. Please help in this problem. I have gotten a spinner in which there are 5 options in which you can attach any of the following : Link, Image, Video, Code and Pdf. I am right now stuck in video.

spinner code :

```
   attachments.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                if (!attachments.getSelectedItem().equals("Add Attachments")){

                    if (attachments.getSelectedItem().equals("Link")){

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AskQuestionActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Paste The Link You Want to Add");
// | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
                        final EditText input = new EditText(AskQuestionActivity.this);
                        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                        builder.setView(input);

                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                String attachments_link = input.getText().toString();
                                allAttachments.add(attachments_link);
                                theAttachments.append("\n" + attachments_link);
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        builder.show();
                    } else if (attachments.getSelectedItem().equals("Image")){

                        if (image5.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
//                            Intent intent = new Intent(
//                                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
//                                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
//                            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(AskQuestionActivity.this, "Sorry:( You can't add any more images.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else if (attachments.getSelectedItem().equals("Video")){

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("video/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), LOAD_VIDEO);
                    }
                }

//                theAttachments.setText((CharSequence) allAttachments);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

onActivityResult code :

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        if (image1.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            image1.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (image2.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
            image2.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            image2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (image3.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
            image3.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            image3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (image4.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
            image4.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            image4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (image5.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
            image5.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            image5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    } else if (requestCode == LOAD_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

        Uri videoCaptureUri = data.getData();
        video1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        video1.setVideoURI(videoCaptureUri);
        video1.start();
    }
}
```

I am not sure what the problem is. Please help. And thank you in advance.

Comment: log the video Uri and it's valid or not

Comment: Ok, will do it.

Comment: Print your video Uri before you play and check it if it's valid or not

Comment: It is not showing in my logs. That is there is no message only coming

Comment: Is it that there is some error with request code because it is not going into onActivityResult() method

Comment: are you trying this from a fragment?

Comment: No, this is from an activity